# How to set TTL for a mongo DB document through a node js route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a delete account route to delete an users information after certain days. I had used SetTimeOut() function to achieve this. But the problem is if in case for some reason the server gets restarted this does not works. So, is there any other method to achieve this.
Thank you.

Below is the code,

```
router.post("/delete", async (req, res, next) => {
  const mailId = req.body.email;
  const deletionTime = moment().format("DD-MMM-YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
  await Register.findOne({ email: mailId })
    .exec()
    .then(async (result) => {
      if (req.body.password === result.password) {
        await Register.updateOne(
          { email: mailId },
          {
            $set: {
              accountDeleted: true,
              deletionFeedback: req.body.deletionFeedback,
              latitude: req.body.latitude,
              longitude: req.body.longitude,
              deletionDate: deletionTime,
              deletionIP: req.body.deletionIP,
              isp: req.body.isp,
              location: req.body.location,
            },
          }
        )
          .exec()
          .then(async (result) => {
            setTimeout(async function(){
              await Register.updateOne(
                { email: mailId },
                {
                  $set: {
                    permanentlyDeleted: true,
                  },
                }
              )
                .exec();
            }, 60000);
            res.status(200).json({
              userDeleted: true,
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).json({
              userDeleted: false,
            });
          });
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({
          result: 0,
          message: "Invalid password.",
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        result: 0,
        message: "Invalid Email ID.",
      });
    });
});
```

The thing is if I restart the server the function inside setTimeOut() method doesn't work. Is there any alternative for this.

Comment: What is the exact error which terminates the node-process? Also some code would be helpful...